# iOS Mjpeg encoding and muxing to MP4

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, mp4, mjpeg

I need to dev an app to encode a Mjpeg stream into an MP4 in ipad/iphone.
Are there available iOS API that I can use to encode & mux (hopefully hardware accelerated).

Comment: You can open a 4:2:0 mjpeg stream and encode to h.264 in the same way as the AVDecodeEncode example here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17606933/using-ffmpeg-to-display-video-on-iphone/17622379#17622379

Comment: Hey, thank you for your comment. I will have a look at AVDecodeEncode.